# Perl regex to skip if anchor href value start with "#"

Tags: regex, perl

I am parsing URLs from string using regular expression and want to skip if anchor href value start with "#".

From below string, I want to skip this
to display as it is "`<a href="#C4">https://www.google.com</a>`"

```
my $text = qq~ <a href="#C4">https://www.google.com</a>
    
    <a href="">https://www.google.com</a>
    
    content1 <video> https://google.com/ </video>my content2<video>https://google.com/</video>~;
```

I am using this regex for this but not getting desired output:

```
$text =~ s/(^|\s|\>|\()(?:<a(?:[^>]*)\>)?((https|ftp):\/\/)([^\r\n<>]*)(?:\<\/a\>)?/$1<a href="$2$4">$2$4\<\/a\>/gi;
```

The above regex return output :

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>

<a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>

content1 <video> <a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a> </video>my content2<video><a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a></video>
```

it's not skipping first anchor as it has "#" at start in href.  Please help.

Comment: The obvious answer would be "Why don't you use an HTML parser"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to make it work using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`: when there's `href="#` inside the `<a`, the match fails and doesn't backtrack. See [perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre) for details.

```perl
$text =~ s{(^|\s|>|\()
           (?:<a[^>]+href=['"]?\#.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
             |<a[^>]*>|)      # If there wasn't href="#, work the old way.
           ((?:https|ftp)://) #2
           ([^\r\n<>]*)       #3
           (?:</a>)?
          }{$1<a\ href="$2$3">$2$3</a>}xgi;
```

I also used `s{}{}` to avoid backslashed slashes and `/x` to make it more readable and turn on comments.